# Automation on google scholar alerts

Tags: google-scholar, automation

I would like to follow articles that cite several researchers in my field.
I created a google scholar alert on those researchers, however, I'm getting around 70 emails per week and most of them contain duplications (if the same article cites two of the researchers, I'll get two emails).

I would be happy to hear about a way to filter the duplication. Some possible approaches:

- A way to export those alerts into google spreadsheet automatically.
- A way to parse those emails using python or other tools.
- A different tool that gives a list of recent papers that relate to those researchers (e.g., using Zotero or Mendeley)

(Parseur.com did not work for those emails, for some reason).

Many thanks!

Comment: "A way to parse those emails using python" Well, how you'd do that depends on how  you store those emails in the first place. You could use the python Gmail API, for example, or some easy to read file-based local mailbox program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the python lovers, I created a small script that parses those mails using [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python), combines similar papers and asks for further actions.

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/elikbelik/scholar_alters).

Answer (score 6):

I've been using Google Scholar Alerts for the paper discovery for a while now and faced a very similar issue.

Here is a [scholar-alert-digest](https://github.com/bzz/scholar-alert-digest) script that I wrote to aggregate all unread messages in a Markdown report [image].

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code! I've written a script of my own, I'll add its link later, but I'm sure yours will help me to improve it!

Answer (score -1):

I create a script for this problem: https://github.com/lizeyan/GSAsummary

> If I follow many researcher on Google Scholar (especially subscribing citation or related papers), I will get dozens of emails every week, but many of the items are repeated. And the massive volume of emails makes my inbox particularly crowded and cluttered, making it difficult to find emails.

> This script generates a HTML report for Google Scholar Alerts by reading your emails from your Mail.app (only for macOS), and send this report to you by email. I have only to read this report and can automatically move the orignal alert emails out of inbox via mailbox rules to keep my inbox clean.